# Accessing the implicit ScrollViewer of a Flyout in WinUI in code

Tags: c#, winui-3, scrollviewer, windows-app-sdk

I have a Flyout with content that is longer than the length of the Flyout, so a vertical scrollbar is activated. I wish to get the underlying ScrollViewer so that I can reset the scroll position everytime the Flyout is closed.

Tried getting the content of the flyout, but could not find the ScrollViewer in the Visual Tree.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work using the `Closing` event:

```cs
private void Flyout_Closing(FlyoutBase sender, FlyoutBaseClosingEventArgs args)
{
    if (VisualTreeHelper
        .GetOpenPopupsForXamlRoot(this.XamlRoot)
        .FirstOrDefault() is not { } popup ||
        popup.Child.FindDescendant<ScrollViewer>() is not { } scrollViewer)
    {
        return;
    }

    _ = scrollViewer.ChangeView(horizontalOffset: 0, verticalOffset: 0, zoomFactor: null, disableAnimation: true);
}
```

**NOTE**

`FindDescendant` comes from the [CommunityToolkit.WinUI.Extensions](https://github.com/CommunityToolkit/WindowsCommunityToolkit) NuGet package. Of course, you should be able to also use the `VisualTreeHelper` to get the `ScrollViewer`.